# EXCEPTION java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.api.server.spi.EndpointsServlet

Tags: java, eclipse, google-cloud-endpoints

While trying to access my end point I see:

```
EXCEPTION 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.api.server.spi.EndpointsServlet
at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-e70c8e440ce77391(Request.java)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:375)
at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:91)
at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:71)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:73)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:242)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:453)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:460)
at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:293)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:319)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:311)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:457)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am using Eclipse to deploy google end point for java. The Eclipse project java build path shows that google app engine and cloud end point libraries are added.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the Jar containing `com.google.api.server.spi.EndpointsServlet` in your classpath

Comment: where should i get it from